# Find identical Excel files (except file name and some attributes) in a folder

Tags: excel

Students submit an assignment in Excel. Many students copy someone else's work and submit identical Excel files (The files are identical in every other way except the filename and date/time attributes might be different. Size may be slightly different for some reason unknown to me.).

All the files are in a single folder.

How may I check to see which files are identical (except for filename, some date/time attributes, and minor file size differences)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Duplicate Files Finder](http://doubles.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Tried it with 2 files that look identical to the human eye (students copied each other). It didn't work. Probably because the 2 files sizes have slightly different file sizes (Excel's "Spreadsheet Compare 2013" tool didn't find any differences between the 2 files either).

Comment: Files probably have different meta-data. Right-click each file, open **Properties** and goto the **Details** tab. You will probably see that files have different properties, such as: _Authors_, _Last saved by_, _Content created_ and _Computer_. There isn't much you can do about this, save for writing a utility to compare spreadsheet values cell-by-cell.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should do a pair-wise comparison.  For example, for *6* students, you would compare *15* pairs:

```
compare 1 to 2
compare 1 to 3
compare 1 to 4
compare 1 to 5
compare 1 to 6
compare 2 to 3
compare 2 to 4
compare 2 to 5
compare 2 to 6
compare 3 to 4
compare 3 to 5
compare 3 to 6
compare 4 to 5
compare 4 to 6
compare 5 to 6
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any software that checks all pairs of spreadsheets in a folder and lists those that are identical. The tool suggested by @Serge does a byte-by-byte comparison but that is too restrictive for your purposes. Two students may share a spreadsheet and simply by saving them at different times or with difference software versions the files may have differences at the byte level but no real differences at the level of cell contents.

However, if you have a small number of files and can manually compare each pairing, then the following formula may help you. Suppose the spreadsheets are Student1 and Student2, and they have only one worksheet each, and the meaningful content is restricted to the range A1:Z1000. Then this array formula will return `true` if and only if every cell in the range are identical on the two sheets.

`=AND([Student1]Sheet1!A1:Z1000=[Student2]Sheet1!A1:Z1000)`

(Note that this is an array formula so must be entered using Ctrl-Shift-Enter.)

Once you get that to work for just two files, then you could set up a list of file pairs to compare, perhaps like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+-----------+
| Spreadsheet A | Spreadsheet B | Identical |
+---------------+---------------+-----------+
| Student1      | Student2      | FALSE     |
| Student1      | Student3      | TRUE      |
| Student2      | Student3      | FALSE     |
+---------------+---------------+-----------+
```

where the formula in C2 is `{=AND(INDIRECT(CONCAT("'[",A2,".xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:Z1000"))=INDIRECT(CONCAT("'[",B2,".xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:Z1000")))}`